# Can ST_Segmentize create equal length segments?

Tags: postgis

`SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Segmentize(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 10 0)'), 3));` gives `LINESTRING(0 0,3 0,6 0,9 0,10 0)` but the expected result is `LINESTRING(0 0,2.5 0,5 0,7.5 0,10 0)`. How can this be done?

See for example the documentation for qgis:densifygeometriesgivenaninterval:

> "E.g. specifying a distance 3 would cause the segment [0 0] -> [10 0]
>   to be converted to [0 0] -> [2.5 0] -> [5 0] -> [7.5 0] -> [10 0],
>   since 3 extra nodes are required on the segment and spacing these at
>   2.5 increments allows them to be evenly spaced over the segment."

Comment: as per the [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Segmentize.html), `ST_Segmentize` will return the line divided into segments with the spezified *max_length* parameter; you could dynamically set the *max_length* parameter, with e.g. `(ST_Length(geom) / 4)`

Comment: But then I would have to calculate and set the _max_length_ parameter for each segment individually, right? That would complicate the code significantly. Is there another function in PostGIS that works like qgis:densifygeometriesgivenaninterval?

Comment: try `ST_Segmentize(geom, ST_Length(geom) / 4)`

Comment: That does not seem to work for lines with multiple segments because `ST_Length(geom)` returns the length of the whole polyline.

Comment: Consider a polyline with 2 segments. For example `SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Segmentize(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0,10 0,10 4)'), 3));` returns `LINESTRING(0 0,3 0,6 0,9 0,10 0,10 3,10 4)` but the expected output (for parity with qgis) would be `LINESTRING(0 0,2.5 0,5 0,7.5 0,10 0,10 2,10 4)`. There is no single expression to pass as _max_length_ instead of 3 to get that. Therefore some other function seems to be needed.

Comment: ah okay, that differs a little from your initial question and is a little more complex in PostGIS. `ST_Segmentize` only inserts vertices where none was found within *max_distance* from the last. in general, you'd need to split each linestring into it's segments first (effectively getting new geometries), run above command on all segments, and collect them back into the original line's constellation.

Comment: You might want to try the Linear Referencing functions http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Linear_Referencing to reference at fixed distances along a LineString.